# Netgear AP mode without ethernet

Tags: networking, router, wireless-access-point, repeater

I have D6400 and previously had a repeater WN2000RPTv2 which was damaged by lightning.
I also have an old N600 (DGND3700v2) which is currently unused.

The N600 supports an AP mode, but the only documentation that I can find regarding this suggests that the AP mode device needs to be connected to the primary device via an ethernet cable.

Is there any way to get the N600 to work as a wireless repeater without a cabled connection, similar to the WN2000RPTv2?

Answer (score 1):

That functionality is usually hard coded into the software of the router. If that option isn't available under advanced settings within the Netgear interface, then "technically" you're router doesn't provide that functionality. However, that said, you could attempt to install Tomato firmware over the the Netgear genie and follow a guide like the one found [here](http://www.bxtra.net/articles/2012-12-24/how-to-setup-wireless-repeater-wireless-ethernet-bridge-on-wireless-router-with) to setup wireless repeating.